# Convergence of a positive series

Tags: calculus

Prove that $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \sqrt[n] 2 -1$$ diverges.

tried to write it as a partial sum:
$$S_k = \sum_{n=1}^k \sqrt[n] 2 -1 = 2 - 1 + \sqrt 2 - 1 + \sqrt[3] 2 - 1 + ... + \sqrt[k] 2 - 1 = (2 + \sqrt 2 + \sqrt[3] 2+ ... + \sqrt[k] 2) - k$$
$$ \le k \sqrt[k] 2 - k = k(\sqrt[k] 2 - 1) \to ln2 ~~(l'hopital)$$

can you help me find a series to compair to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We want to get some idea of the size of $2^{1/n}-1$ for large $n$. One way is to look at the ratio
$$\frac{2^{1/n}-1}{1/n}.$$
Replace $1/n$ by $t$. We will investigate the behaviour of 
$$\frac{2^t-1}{t}$$
as $t$ approaches $0$ through positive values.

Note that $2^t=e^{t\ln 2}$. Using L'Hospital's Rule, or in another way, we find that 
$$\lim_{t\to 0^+}\frac{e^{t\ln 2}-1}{t}=\ln 2.$$

Thus $\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{2^n-1}{1/n}=\ln 2$. By Limit Comparison with the series $\sum_1^\infty \frac{1}{n}$, it follows that our series diverges.

Answer (score 0):

$$e^x=1+x+O(x^2)$$
$$\implies2^{1/n}=e^{\frac{\ln(2)}{n}}=1+\frac{\ln(2)}{n}+O(\frac{1}{n^2})$$
So we have that:

$$\sum_{n\ge 1}2^{1/n}-1=\ln(2)\sum_{n\ge 1}\frac{1}{n}+O(1)$$

And since the rhs diverges we know the lhs must as well.